# Passing char *array[] as a function argument and processing it

Tags: pointers

Passing char *array[] to function

Hello,

I have the following example code which basically generate a string of selectable options for an display element.

`char *option_list[] = {

```
    "Option 1",
    "Option 2",
    "Option 3",
    "Option 4",
    "Option 5",
    "Option 6",
    "Option 7",
    "Option 8",
    "Option 9",
    "Option 10",
    NULL
```

};

void load_roller( lv_obj_t *roller ) {

```
char        *roller_options;
char        *ptr, **list_ptr;
uint16_t    idx;
uint32_t    buf_size = 0, entry_cnt = 0;

list_ptr = option_list;
while( *list_ptr != NULL ) {
    buf_size += strlen( *list_ptr++ );
    entry_cnt++;
}
buf_size += entry_cnt;      // The entry_cnt variable is the locations required for the \n characters and the terminating NULL for the drop down list texts.
roller_options = malloc( buf_size );
ptr = roller_options;
for( idx = 0; idx < entry_cnt; idx++ ) {
    ptr += snprintf( ptr, (buf_size - (ptr - roller_options)), "%s\n", option_list[idx]);
}
*(ptr-1) = 0; // This will strip the final newline character and terminate the string with a NULL
lv_roller_set_options(roller, roller_options, LV_ROLLER_MODE_NORMAL);
free( roller_options );
```

}`

Now it would be better to passe the "option_list" as an argument to the load_roller function. But I'm very bad with pointers and hence quiet lost.

My best guess would have been to pass the option_list as pointer and dereference it in the funtion. This compiles but I only get the first entry of the option_list as output. Therefore I have checked the entry_cnt value and it is 1. So what is it, that I'm doing wrong?

`void load_roller( lv_obj_t *roller, char *option_list ) {

```
char        *roller_options;
char        *ptr, **list_ptr;
uint16_t    idx;
uint32_t    buf_size = 0, entry_cnt = 0;

list_ptr = &option_list;
while( *list_ptr != NULL ) {
    buf_size += strlen( *list_ptr++ );
    entry_cnt++;
}
buf_size += entry_cnt;      // The entry_cnt variable is the locations required for the \n characters and the terminating NULL for the drop down list texts.
roller_options = malloc( buf_size );
ptr = roller_options;
for( idx = 0; idx < entry_cnt; idx++ ) {
    ptr += snprintf( ptr, (buf_size - (ptr - roller_options)), "%s\n", &option_list[idx]);
}
*(ptr-1) = 0; // This will strip the final newline character and terminate the string with a NULL
lv_roller_set_options(roller, roller_options, LV_ROLLER_MODE_NORMAL);
free( roller_options );`
```

called from the main programm with load_roller( ui_widget, *list );

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. Since * to array [] is basically a pointer to a pointer I will have to pass ** as argument into the function.